# Updating data dyanamically using php

Tags: php, forms

The values are not updated in mysql database while using the following code.
I wanted to update database hell with the new values entered in textbox.

```
    <?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","host","pass");
    mysql_select_db("Host",$con);
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    $upd= "UPDATE hell SET name='".$_POST['name']."'
    WHERE rno='".$_POST['rno']."'";
    mysql_query($upd,$con);
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM hell";
    $rec=mysql_query($sql,$con);
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Roll No.</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($arr=mysql_fetch_assoc($rec))
    {
    echo "<form action=untitled2.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type=text name='name' value='".$arr['name']."'>"."
    </td>";
    echo "<td>".$arr['rno']."</td>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name='rno' id='rno' value='".$arr['rno']."'>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type=submit value='update'>"."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Sorry not used to this. btw edited the ques. plz help.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['update'])){` this condition will never be met.

Answer (score 0):

So many errors in your code :

1) Dont use `mysql_*`. It is deprecated and removed from PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

2) Mysql connection should be used like this :

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","host","pass");
mysql_select_db("Host",$con);
```

3) Your update query is wrong and it's execution.
Try this :

```
$upd= "UPDATE hell SET name='".$_POST['name']."' WHERE rno='".$_POST['rno']."'";
mysql_query($upd,$con);
```

4) Select query execution should be like this :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM hell";
$rec=mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

5) You can not use `form` inside `table`. It's invalid html format.

6) Read this  : [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)